# How to prove that I am part of a list without revealing my identity?

Tags: javascript, authentication, encryption, cryptography, digital-signature

Let's suppose and scenario like a secret voting scheme, at the ID verification step.

**Considerations:**

1. There is a public list of identities of people who are able to vote (ex, people who live in a certain town).
2. The identity confirmation process is entrusted to a central server (Bob).
3. Bob is the authenticator and also the same who "give the ballots" to voters.
4. Users send requests remotely and decentralized (ex, with their respective devices).
5. The idea is that the ID is never sent via the communication channel.
6. The is no specific ID method, could be anything that does the task, digital signature, etc...

**Conditions to be met**

1. The Alice (the voter) must prove to Bob that she is on that list without revealing her identity.
2. The Bob (the server) has to ensure that no one who is not on the list can access to the voting.

How this problem is called and what is a practical example of the solution?

*PD: The voting execution process is not important in this problem, it only deals with identity verification.*

Comment: Sounds like both Alice and Bob need a trusted third party. If Alice will verify with Carol (third party) and carol will tell Bob that the credentials are valid without saying whose those credentials are.

Comment: If Carol and Bob communicate, Carol can tell him who Alice is, then Carol should be trusted. It would be almost the same if Bob saw the identities and promised not to tell anyone. Alice should not trust to them.

Comment: That's why it's called a **trusted** party. It's how online payments work, for example - Visa is the third party that both me and the seller trust when I make a transaction. Sure, it's not credentials in that case but payment details that pass around but it's still the same idea - Visa is the one doing the verification and making assurances. It's also how HTTPS works, too - the server gives me some credentials and I verify that's correct with a certificate authority which is my trusted party. Same idea with a system like Keycloak for a login - it acts as Carol when a user logs in to a server.

Comment: Sorry, may be my question is not very detailed. The idea is that users feel safe that the information they are sending to that entity is not compromising. If Bob knows Alice's identity, Bob can know who she voted for. In voting schemes there should not be trusted parties at all. This scheme has the intention that the execution of the vote is done through blockchain, but I have not solved an anonymous way to prove identity because Bob is also who give the ballots to Alice.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is called a [zero-knowledge proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof). This sort of question is probably more suited to [crypto.stackexchange.com](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your time, r3mainer, I have read and understand theoretically how Zero Knowledge Proof works, but I can't think of how to apply it to this problem, because there are different kinds of ZKP. I already asked the question on Crypto Stack Exchange, I want to do a bounty on Stack Overflow, too.

Comment: @FabricioEspinoza There seems to be something missing here. The vote tabulation service (Carol) should be separate from the authentication service (Bob). Alice authenticates to Bob and gets a token. Alice sends the token and vote to Carol. Carol asks Bob if the token is valid. If Bob validates the token, Carol records the vote. Bob doesn't know how Alice voted, Carol doesn't know who Alice is.

Comment: @Barmar I think Bob is doing the vote count, so Carol and Bob's roles are reversed. But otherwise, correct - the trusted authority doesn't know what action Alice takes while the vote counter doesn't know who voted, just that the vote is valid.

Comment: @VLAZ Right. I misunderstood the role when it said "Bob has to ensure that no one who is not on the list can access the voting", so I thought Bob was the authenticator (or trying to serve both roles).

Comment: Sorry again, Bob is the ID authenticator and also who give the ballots to the voters (i will edit the post), this is made by a Blockchain transaction. The idea is a solution that does not need a third participant, because you could say that someone authenticate and other one give the ballots, in fact its a possible solution, but I want just a bilateral communication.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about programming and it has been [cross posted to cryptograpy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/84213/1172). Please do not cross post.